# Sending fix amount of ETH without manually input value in remix

Tags: remix, ether, send

I tried writing a contract so that we can send eth without inputting value manually in this field in remix.

[image]

So, we just need to click the sendEth button below ( no need to input anything)
[image]

The following is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

contract Payment{
   address  payable receiver = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2);
   uint price = 5 ether;

   function sendEth() public payable {
        (bool sent, ) = receiver.call{value: price}("");
        require(sent, "Fail to send");
    }
    
}
```

Since, the suggested method to send eth is by call, so I try using the call method.
However, when I deploy it and click the sendEth button, it did not work, and the following is the error:
[image]

Eth can be sent if I input the value manually, however  in my case I hope that the payment can be done automatically. Could it possibly be done? Any explanation would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Payment contract does not have 5 ether balance that is the reason why this is reverted.
either have a receive(){} fallback to deposit eth to your contract, or send 5 ethers when sendEth() is called.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work the way you want it to.

When you call the `sendEth` function, it basically sends the ether from the `payment` contract to the `receiver` address, but for that, it's pretty obvious that the `payment` contract needs to have that much of an amount. So it takes you back to the original problem of manually sending those 5 ETH while calling the function.

You can avoid this by sending a big chunk of ETH one time and then sending 5 ETH every time you call the `sendEth` function, for example, you sent 100 ETH once and then you call the `sendEth` function 20 times. For this you will need to include a `receive` or `fallback` function in your contract.

As long as you are using remix, you'll need to manually enter the ETH amount, either one time for big amount or multiple times with a small amount.

Comment: I see. So, in the case of sending eth from the contract, the contract needs to have some balance. What about sending directly from an account to another account in remix, is this possible?

Comment: Nope, it's not. This would be possible in a wallet like metamas etc. or by writing a simple JS/TS script. Remix doesn't have an interface to work with wallets in general, it's made to work with contracts only.